# Uncaught ReferenceError: AppRootToken is not defined - Ionic V3

Tags: ionic3

When I build my app with the command:

```
ionic cordova build android
```

My app works normally. And when I build with the command:

```
ionic cordova build android --prod
```

The build process was finished successfully. But when I install and run on my devices, I got an error like this:

```
> Uncaught ReferenceError: AppRootToken is not defined
>     at Function.t.forRoot (vendor.js:1)
>     at main.js:1
>     at Object.372 (main.js:1)
>     at e (vendor.js:1)
>     at window.webpackJsonp (vendor.js:1)
>     at main.js:1
```

I don't know what is going wrong, This error just appear after I do

`cordova platform add android@6.3.0`

Does Anyone ever happen like this?

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: I think `cordova platform add android@6.3.0` make the error. So, I revert that action. But, some of cordova plugin that I used need new android version. So, when I build to APK, I run this command `ionic cordova build android --prod -- -- --minSdkVersion=21`. For now, that solve my problem.